# Material UI / MUI Systems: How can I tell TypeScript that the theme is passed by the provider?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I have the following modified demo code from Material UI docs:

```
function ThemeUsage() {
  const theme = {
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#000",
      },
    },
  } as const;

  type DefaultThemeType = { theme: typeof theme };

  const MyThemeComponent = styled("div")(({ theme }: DefaultThemeType) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  }));

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyThemeComponent>Styled div with theme</MyThemeComponent>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

The TS compiler is telling me the following error while hovering over the MyThemeComponent element:

> Property 'theme' is missing in type '{ children: string; }' but required in type 'DefaultThemeType'.

So the compiler wants, that I add the theme as a prop to the "MyThemeComponent". But in MUI Systems the theme is passed through the provider and is accessible inside the styled return function. So how can I tell the compiler about that?

I have already tried some different types, also to remove the type, but then I lose type-checking inside the Styled-Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use either `Theme` type from `@mui` or the [`createTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#api) builder function for `@mui`'s `styled` function type to automatically remove the `theme` as a required prop (since it will indeed be automatically passed by MUI):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#000",
    },
  },
});

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  {/* ✅️ Okay */}
  <MyThemeComponent>Styled div with theme</MyThemeComponent>
</ThemeProvider>

// Or:
const MyThemeComponent = styled("div")(
  ({ theme }: { theme: Theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  })
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: thank you for your answer! That seems to solve the problem, but is it also possible to provide a theme in an different structure, that is not like the Theme interface provided by MUI?

Comment: If you are referring to [custom variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#custom-variables), then follow the TS module augmentation technique described in this linked doc.